# $2^{X}$ compact $\iff$ X compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $T_{1}$ space and let $2^{X}$ have the Vietoris topology.

I saw a recent post on this forum about $2^{X}$ being separable $\iff$ $X$ is separable and was wondering if the same holds for compactness; i.e.,

$2^{X}$ is compact if and only if $X$ is compact.

Does this hold?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does (without assumptions on $X$). Also for connectedness (when $X$ is $T_1$ IIRC).

Suppose $2^X$ is compact.
If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, then $\{[U]: U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is an open cover of $2^X$ (where $[U]=\{F \in 2^X: F \cap U \neq \emptyset\}$ is a subbasic open set of $2^X$. If $[U_1], \ldots [U_n]$ is a finite subcover, $\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i = X$ or otherwise $F:= X\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ would be a member of $2^X$ not covered by $[U_1], \ldots [U_n]$, contradiction. So $\mathcal{U}$ has a finite subcover and $X$ is compact.

For the reverse (so we assume $X$ is compact) we use [Alexander's subbase lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Alexander_subbase_theorem), where we also use the subbasic $\langle U \rangle = \{F \in 2^X: F \subseteq U\}$ besides the previously used $[U]$ sets (these form a standard subbase for $2^X$).

Let $\{[U_i]: i \in I\} \cup \{\langle V_j \rangle: j \in J\}$ be any cover of $2^X$ by subbasic elements.

Consider $C:= X\setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$. If $C$ is empty, the sets $U_i$ cover $X$ and so finitely many of them cover $X$, say $U_{i_1}, \ldots, U_{i_n}$. Then if $A \in 2^X$, then $A$ is non-empty and contains some $x$ which must lie in some $U_{i_k}$ for $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and then $A \in [U_{i_k}]$ and so the sets $\{[U_{i_k}]: k=1, \ldots,n\}$ form a finite subcover of the subbasic cover and we're done.

So we're left with the case that $C \neq \emptyset$ and so $C \in 2^X$ and by definition it misses all $U_i$ so is covered by some $\langle V_{j_0} \rangle$ instead. We then cover $X\setminus V_{j_0}$ by finitely many $U_{i_1}, \ldots U_{i_n}$ and similarly to above show that $$\{[U_{i_k}]: k=1, \ldots,n\} \cup \{\langle V_{j_0} \rangle\}$$ is a finite subcover of the subbasic cover and so $2^X$ is compact.

It isn't always this straightforward wrt properties preserved between $X$ and $2^X$ though. Surprising fact : if $2^X$ is $T_4$ (normal and Hausdorff) then $X$ must be compact and Hausdorff (and then the same also holds for $2^X$ again): it's harder for the larger space to be "nice" without being "very nice", roughly speaking. And if $2^X$ is even hereditarily normal (aka completely normal), it must even be compact metrisable and $X$ too.